# Friendship page in Facebook

Tags: facebook, friend-list

I want to see the Facebook friendship page between me and my friend.

How can I see that page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
https://www.facebook.com/YOUR_ID?and=YOUR_FRIENDS_ID
```

Or

```
https://www.facebook.com/friendship/YOUR_ID/YOUR_FRIENDS_ID/
```

Where the IDs can be either the numeric ID or the chosen username. It works also if you are not friends with the respective person. You need only the id of his/her profile.

Otherwise:

1. Go to your friend's page
2. Click on the "three-dots" icon in the upper-right corner
   [image]
3. Click on **See Friendship**
   [image]